# Install plugin for plugin

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, original-vim

I'm trying to use [nerdtree-git-plugin](https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin) for [nerdtree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) to be able to see git information within vim

I'm using vim 8.2 and so have been using the built in package manager. I have the nerdtree files in `~/.vim/pack/vendor/start` and that works fine but putting the nerdtree-git-plugin files here doesn't seem to work?

When I say doesn't seem to work, I mean that I can't see anything git related in my status bar in vim when I have a git tracked file open:
[image]

This appears to be the functionality of this plugin from the gif:
[image]
on [nerdtree-git-plugin](https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin)

Where I'm storing the files:

[image]

If I run `:scriptnames` then the git plugin does seem to be showing
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why "it doesn't seem to work"? Do you have any errors? Which ones? What did you do to test if it works? Does your plugin shows somewhere in the output of `:scriptnames`? This information will be useful for other people who will try to help you

Comment: @statox question updated with your input thanks

Comment: So I'm not familiar with the plugin but if you want to have things appearing in the status line don't you need to edit your `statusline` setting? When you open NERDtree do the symbols show next to the modified files? Maybe that's a good way to tell if the plugin is actually working (since it seems to source the autolad files my guess is that it is working but not like you expect, but I could be completely wrong)

Comment: @statox I'm not sure about the statusline setting and wouldn't know what to set it to. Nope when in NERDTree I don't see any symbols next to modified files

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Comment: I agree a bit with statox; the statusline is probably something like airline + fugitive; nerdtree-git-whatever is probably about adding status symbols to nerdtree.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble noted about the images of text, sorry I got a bit carried away after trying to read the gif from the nerdtree-git-plugin page. I saw airline and fugitive come up in my searches for the git plugin, I'll have a look at these then to see if they can do a similar thing - any further advice here? I would like to keep nerdtree